# Problema al pasar una imagen y un grupo de checkbox por medio de ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Buen dia, tengo un problema al momento de pasar los parametros de un formulario tipo file y un grupo de checkbox por medio de ajax.

Mi código es el siguiente

```js
$("#form_img").submit(function(event){

  $('#p2').show();
 
  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();
 
  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  var buckets = new Array();
        $( "input[name='checkpoint[]']:checked" ).each( function() {
                buckets.push( $( this ).val() );
        } );
 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'img_point/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      //alert(returndata);
      $('.resulttemp').html(returndata);
       alertify.warning('Por favor espere…');
      $('#p2').hide();
    }
  });
 
  return false;
});
```

Como hago para pasar la variable buckets utilizando el código ajax, he intentado con el metodo data: {buckets : buckets, formData:formData}, pero no funciona, agradezco toda la ayuda posible. Muchas gracias.

Comment: y como hiciste para leerlo en php??

Comment: Hola, en php obtuve las variables por método post y por medio de un bucle for recorrí los datos para ejecutar una acción, este fue el codigo que use: $property_typesRequest = $this->input->post('buckets', TRUE);


     foreach($property_typesRequest as $value){ 

       $name_img=$this->upload_img($value);

       $id_edit = $value;

       $path_img = $id_edit."/".$name_img;

        $data_point=array(

           'img_point'=> $path_img   
                        
        );

        $this->update_pointdb($data_point, $id_edit);


      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Así por ejemplo:

```
$("input[name='checkpoint[]']:checked").each(function() {
  formData.append("buckets[]", this.value);
});
```

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de implementar y funciona!, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hola este es el código final que use:

```js
$("#form_img").submit(function(event){

   event.preventDefault();
 
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  

  $("input[name='checkpoint[]']:checked").each(function() {
    formData.append("buckets[]", this.value);
  });
 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'img_point',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
  
      $('.response').html(returndata);
      
    }
  });
 
  return false;
});
```

```html
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_img"  method="post">

   <input type="file"  id="file" name="userfile" required>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkpoint[]' value='1'>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkpoint[]' value='2'>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkpoint[]' value='3'>

   <input  type="submit" value="Cambiar"/>
 
</form>

<div class='response'></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la respuesta. Quizás sería mucho más productivo agregar un pequeño texto describiendo qué es lo que particularmente modificaste, de modo que le pueda ser más útil a otros usuarios